# "...args: never[]" vs "...args: unknown[]" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typing

New to TypeScript here. I'm trying to define an interface for "things that have a `.toString()` method", where the `.toString()` can accept any number of arguments, of any type.

The following code is a minimum example, and using `...args: never[]` as the arguments to `toString()` in the interface seems to work correctly. My question is **why; can someone explain to me what the difference between `unknown` and `never` is in this case**?

```
interface Stringable {
  // toString: (...args: any[]) => string; // works but type-unsafe
  // toString: (...args: unknown[]) => string; // causes num and object to error
  toString: (...args: never[]) => string; // seems to work
}

const num: Stringable = 4;
const word: Stringable = "hello";
const obj: Stringable = { toString: (text: string) => text + "!!" };

console.log(num.toString());
console.log(word.toString());
console.log(obj.toString("world"));
```

Comment: I can't [reproduce this working without error on TSC v4.9.4](https://tsplay.dev/m0blaw). Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Strange, it was working for me locally and on the cloud sandbox before posting... and now it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`never` is the type you can never assign anything to but you can always assign from

```
let x: never = 1; // can't assign annything to
let o: string = x; // can assign from
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBB2IBuIBOEC8ECMBuCA9ARAMYCG8A5JGQM60CWA5vBBfAJ5gAWD8TEMAHsAsAChQkIXFphUfAVij4ipCm3rNWAM1RCAthCA)

`unknown` is the opposite, it is the type you can always assign to, but you can never assign from

```
let x: unknown = 1; // can assign anything to
let o: string = x; // can't assign from
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=41&pln=2&pc=33#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBCuA7A1og9gd0RAvBAjANwQD0JEAxgIbZUDOdAlgOa2ICeYAFo4sxGDQBYAFChIaOHTAAnXvzxRiZSjQDkkek1YQAZjLQBbCEA)

In the context of a function signature `(...args: never[]) => string` will be a signature that can never be invoke with any arguments (since we can never assign anything to an parameter of type `never`). The consequence of this, is that we can assign any function implementation to such a signature, because if we pass in an argument of type never, since `never` is assignable type, that `never` value is assignable to a value of that parameter.

```
interface Stringable {
  toString: (...args: never[]) => string; 
}

// Since this is not a error
const obj: Stringable = { toString: (text: string) => text.toUpperCase() + "!!" };

// This has to be a TS error
console.log(obj.toString(1));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5nARgGxQG8BYAKGWTAHt1MQsAuZACgDoO4osBnZkCADdoAbQC6ASmQBeAHzIeGbAG5k5AL7lyAem1pQSKgAtgPZKeQhqYZHGTQo1KOQTUQi5NVwArZnWx4hDLIRFS0SgzMLJAAHmDMivRYUnJUEHFsNACqAA450ADCcDwQLFIA1MgARACENVXI6spaZLrIAComZkbFYci4KHbtqPZQjs5kru7UhGz41FgsXt6Z4UksAIwSEs1kQA)

An unfortunate consequence is that while we can't pass in arguments, we can still call the function with no arguments. This seems  like an unsoundness in the type system.

```
interface Stringable {
  toString: (...args: never[]) => string; 
}

const obj: Stringable = { toString: (text: string) => text.toLowerCase() + "!!" };

console.log(obj.toString("X")); // ts error
console.log(obj.toString()); // callable, will throw a runtime error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5nARgGxQG8BYAKGWTAHt1MQsAuZACgDoO4osBnZkCADdoAbQC6ASmQBeAHzIeGbAG5k5AL7lyCaiEXJquAFbM62PIRnIiVWkobMWkAB5hmi+lilyqEV2xoAGWoAd2gAYTgeCBYpAGpkACIAQmTE5HVlLTIdPWpCNnxqLBZDIwC7TxZEgA1EiQlVAHomqh5kaChqKG1dHnyIQuLS4wqzBljG5BbkBDh8fAsIABpkEOAFqgALLpDkOGQoAFdwYABbFE7u8iA)

`(...args: unknown[]) => string` is a function signature that can take any number argument, with any values. This means that an implementation must be able to handle any values passed in. This means we can assign a function that does not handle it's arguments at all (such as `String.toString(): string`) but we can't assign one that needs specific types for any of it's arguments (such as `Number.toString(radix?: number | undefined): string`, or `obj.toString: (text: string) => string`)

Intuitively we ca see we want an error:

```
interface Stringable {
  toString: (...args: unknown[]) => string; 
}

// IF this is not an error
const obj: Stringable = { toString: (text: string) => text.toUpperCase() + "!!" };

//  this is a runtime error
console.log(obj.toString(1));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5nARgGxQG8BYAKGWTAHt1MQsAuZACgDoO4osBnZgVxABrENQDuIANoBdAJTIAvAD5kPDNgDcycgF9y5APQHkASQBiVABbAeyG8lFhkcEMmhRqUcgmog1yalwAK2Y6bDxCRWQiKlp1BmYWSAAPMGY1eix5ZSoIVLYaAFUAB2LoAGE4HggWeQBqZAAiAEJmxuQdDX0yI0owa1t7OGQoQTBgAFsUd09vXx5qQjZ8aiwWQKCCuMyWAEZZWS6yIA)

We can't in principle create a function signature that can hold safely all the following signatures: `Number.toString(radix?: number | undefined): string`, `obj.toString: (text: string) => string`, `String.toString(): string`. We can't do this because `Number.toString` and `obj.toString` expect conflicting types as the first argument. The only safe way to call both would be with an argument that satisfies  BOTH signatures, which would be `string` and `number` which is  `string & number` which is `never`.

The only `toString` we can safely represent one without parameters:

```
interface Stringable {
  toString: () => string; 
}

const num: Stringable = 4;
const word: Stringable = "hello";
const obj: Stringable = { toString: (text?: string) => text + "!!" };

console.log(num.toString());
console.log(word.toString());
console.log(obj.toString());
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5nARgGxQG8BYAKGWTAHt1MQsAuZACgEpkBeAPmQGcM2ANzJyAX3LkE1EAOQgArgFtmdbHkJdkAFiFSZcgO7UoAE1WCGGlJ2QAiABYR8+anb1lpssMmq4AVhb0OAQ2yERUtJZMrJAAHmAA-MwCwRw8VBAJyADU9gCE+XbIYh76stSEAHSuWCyKSlU0agzsbB5efJUQNdR1xmZNUcFtHQbdvXV+-kMtdWztQA)

Answer (score 0):

`unknown` is basically polite (safer) `any`. You use it when type isn't known.

`never` on the other hand is something that never occurs - function without return value returns `never`. Function which has `never[]` for spread argument takes no parameter.

Error occurs when you try to call the function. In your example:

```js
interface Stringable {
  toString: (...args: never[]) => string;
}

const obj: Stringable = { toString: (text: string) => text + "!!" };

console.log(obj.toString("world")); // -> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

For you usecase I think using generic type is best:

```
interface Stringable<T> {
  toString: (...args: T[]) => string;
}

const obj: Stringable<string> = { toString: (text) => text + "!!" };

console.log(obj.toString("world"));
```

There is nice comparision table between types in [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability).

Comment: A generic type won't work for methods with more than one argument type, e.g. `toString(text: string, int: number)`. It also doesn't work well with builtins like `String.prototype.toString()` which takes no arguments.

Comment: "Function without return value returns `never`" is misleading. `console.log` doesn't have a return value yet it returns `undefined`. `never` is only returned if the program exits before the function can return. For example, `process.exit` returns `never` because it ends the program.